# Oracle 10g - Sort numbers with letters

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, oracle10g

I need to sort the following list of values, dots included:

```
1.
10.
2f.
2c.
2a.
```

I need them sorted in the following order:

```
1.
2a.
2c.
2f.
10.
```

I used the following code on SQL Developer to sort the list:

```
with testdata as
(
select column_value from table (sys.odcivarchar2list
   ('1. '
   ,'10. '
   ,'2f. '
   ,'2b. '
   ,'2a. '))
   )
select column_value
  from testdata
 order by case when replace(translate(trim(column_value),'0123456789','0'),'0','') is null then to_number(column_value) end
         ,column_value
/
```

but I did not get the result I wanted:

```
1.
10.
2a.
2c.
2f.
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexp_substr` to order by numbers in the string first and then by the remaining non-numeric characters. This assumes the string always has number(s) followed by non-numeric character(s).

```
select column_value
from testdata
order by cast(regexp_substr(column_value,'[0-9]+') as int), 
regexp_substr(column_value,'[^0-9]+')
```

Comment: [Some info](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_substr.php) for context